# How to sum up values of two category and show in a column chart in Google Data Studio?

Tags: looker-studio

My data look like this.

There are three branches, ABC, PQR, and XYZ and each one do three types of businesses, Counter Sale, Online Sale and Van sale. I know how to show this data in a column chart as it is, but my requirement is, I want to sum up the counter sale and the van sale by branch and date, let's call it ABC - Offline Sale, PQR - Offline Sale and XYZ - Offline Sale and then show this in a column chart. I have been after this for two days and couldn't find any help online.
I tried to create calculated fields using case statements but it didn't work as expected and  I couldn't really accomplish what I wanted.

| Date | Branch | SALE | PROFIT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01-Jan-23 | ABC - COUNTER SALE | 184518 | 184518 |
| 01-Jan-23 | ABC - VAN SALE | 0 | 0 |
| 01-Jan-23 | ABC - ONLINE | 0 | 0 |
| 01-Jan-23 | XYZ - COUNTER SALE | 144425 | 144425 |
| 01-Jan-23 | XYZ - VAN SALE | 38163 | 38163 |
| 01-Jan-23 | XYZ - ONLINE | 0 | 0 |
| 01-Jan-23 | PQR - COUNTER SALE | 261219 | 261219 |
| 01-Jan-23 | PQR - VAN SALE | 0 | 0 |
| 01-Jan-23 | PQR - ONLINE | 53851 | 53851 |
| 02-Jan-23 | ABC - COUNTER SALE | 280046 | 280046 |
| 02-Jan-23 | ABC - VAN SALE | 97992 | 97992 |
| 02-Jan-23 | ABC - ONLINE | 0 | 0 |
| 02-Jan-23 | XYZ - COUNTER SALE | 276917 | 276917 |
| 02-Jan-23 | XYZ - VAN SALE | 15815 | 15815 |
| 02-Jan-23 | XYZ - ONLINE | 0 | 0 |
| 02-Jan-23 | PQR - COUNTER SALE | 310918 | 310918 |
| 02-Jan-23 | PQR - VAN SALE | 0 | 0 |
| 02-Jan-23 | PQR - ONLINE | 129857 | 129857 |
| 03-Jan-23 | ABC - COUNTER SALE | 197445 | 197445 |
| 03-Jan-23 | ABC - VAN SALE | 39976 | 39976 |
| 03-Jan-23 | ABC - ONLINE | 0 | 0 |
| 03-Jan-23 | XYZ - COUNTER SALE | 206751 | 206751 |
| 03-Jan-23 | XYZ - VAN SALE | 24715 | 24715 |
| 03-Jan-23 | XYZ - ONLINE | 0 | 0 |
| 03-Jan-23 | PQR - COUNTER SALE | 303617 | 303617 |
| 03-Jan-23 | PQR - VAN SALE | 0 | 0 |
| 03-Jan-23 | PQR - ONLINE | 189570 | 189570 |
| 04-Jan-23 | ABC - COUNTER SALE | 203264 | 203264 |
| 04-Jan-23 | ABC - VAN SALE | 84817 | 84817 |
| 04-Jan-23 | ABC - ONLINE | 30793 | 30793 |
| 04-Jan-23 | XYZ - COUNTER SALE | 214984 | 214984 |
| 04-Jan-23 | XYZ - VAN SALE | 23149 | 23149 |
| 04-Jan-23 | XYZ - ONLINE | 0 | 0 |
| 04-Jan-23 | PQR - COUNTER SALE | 287748 | 287748 |
| 04-Jan-23 | PQR - VAN SALE | 0 | 0 |
| 04-Jan-23 | PQR - ONLINE | 540781 | 540781 |
| 05-Jan-23 | ABC - COUNTER SALE | 219093 | 219093 |
| 05-Jan-23 | ABC - VAN SALE | 44327 | 44327 |
| 05-Jan-23 | ABC - ONLINE | 104569 | 104569 |
| 05-Jan-23 | XYZ - COUNTER SALE | 167817 | 167817 |
| 05-Jan-23 | XYZ - VAN SALE | 96145 | 96145 |
| 05-Jan-23 | XYZ - ONLINE | 0 | 0 |
| 05-Jan-23 | PQR - COUNTER SALE | 297488 | 297488 |
| 05-Jan-23 | PQR - VAN SALE | 0 | 0 |
| 05-Jan-23 | PQR - ONLINE | 348895 | 348895 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a calculated field as such:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(Branch,"VAN|COUNTER","OFFLINE")
```

- 

[image]

Comment: As I can see from the output, it has replaced  'van sale' and 'counter sale' with 'offline sale', I don't want to do that if this will be replaced permanently in my original data since I have to use them for other calculations. Is there any other way to accomplish this?

Comment: its a new(separate) calculated field you can create